# Does an idle mysql database consume memory?

Tags: mysql, memory

I have a huge mysql database, which is around 5Gb. I'm using InnoDB for these database tables. I have noticed that PHPMyadmin (MySql is running on a 1Gb VPS) became rather too slow and sometimes unresponsive.

As I don't use the data at all (for the moment), I moved the tables from that database (let's call it database **A**) to another one **B** (I have new tables created every day in **A**)

Now database A has only 300Mb of data. However, PHPMyadmin is still slow, and sometimes unresponsive.

Is this caused by the database **B** even if I'm not using it?

Edit: MySql consumes around 20% of the server memory according to "top". However, checking with the "free" command, 95% of the server memory is allocated. There are no other noticeable programs that consumes memory.

Comment: Data that's not in use will be paged to disk in modern operating systems, even if it did get loaded for no reason (would have to be a very faulty SQL server :) )

Comment: Are you sure that the server is actually low on memory? If you think excessive memory is being used, why haven't you **measured** memory usage? And low memory isn't the only reason for a process to run slowly.

Comment: I'm with @Matt here... why are you assuming it's memory. You could be fighting for a single disk with another process or some other set of processes could be deadlocked trying to create 300 identical directories on an unresponsive NAS (don't ask). Have you identified that the problem is actually memory? If you have, have you identified _what_ is actually using up all the memory. You then answer your own question.

Comment: @MattBall I'm not quite sure that it's memory, but memory consumption indeed is a lot higher than when the server is booted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your server settings (my.cnf). If you configured mySQL to consume 20% of your memory through process based buffer (key_block_size for myISAM or innodb_buffer_pool for INNODB) then mysql will not grow UNLESS a query is using a thread based buffer and that is configured to be large.

If 95% of the system memory is allocated, where is it allocated to? Is the memory in file system cache? Another process?

Also note when you move a database, drop a table, etc. the user based memory for mySQL is flushed is most cases and the buffer needs to refill in mysql, thus the operations you are doing are hitting the disk more.

One other thing. If PHPmyadmin is slow on a new database memory. Your application may be hitting mysql harder for another database forcing all new queries from PHPMyadmin to hit the disk for the new database's tables.

All this logic is controlled by my.cnf changes.